# selecting and utilizing two tables (more detailed explanation in the post)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The title is really poor, i cannot for the life of me figure out how to describe this issue in a title, a more detailed explanation will be provided.

Basically, i have two tables, one with bidders and one with bids. I want to display all the bids and the respective bidders name. In the bid table there isn't a name however, the name is in the bidder table, bidder table has a PK called bidderNumber (basically the unique bidder ID) whilst the bid table has bidderNumber as a FK referencing bidderNumber from the bidder table. Here are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Bidder (
bidderNumber INT,
name VARCHAR(50),
address VARCHAR(50),
credit INT,
PRIMARY KEY (bidderNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Bid (
bidNumber INT,
itemNumber INT,
bidderNumber INT,
bidDate DATE,
bid INT,
PRIMARY KEY (bidNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (itemNumber) REFERENCES Item (itemNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (bidderNumber) REFERENCES Bidder (bidderNumber)
);

INSERT INTO Bidder (bidderNumber, name, address, credit) VALUES
(0, 'Ada Asson', 'HemmaIHuset', 10000),
(1, 'Beda Bsson', 'StuganVidVägen', 70000),
(2, 'Ceasar Csson', 'Någonstans', 25000),
(3, 'Dino Dsson', 'Where', 5000),
(4, 'Eve Esson', 'Bråkmakaregatan', 200000),
(5, 'Fabian Fsson', 'Here', 14000);

INSERT INTO Bid (bidNumber, itemNumber, bidderNumber, bidDate, bid) VALUES
(0, 0, 0, '2019-04-20', 50),
(1, 0, 2, '2019-04-25', 70),
(2, 1, 1, '2019-05-01', 500),
(3, 1, 2, '2019-05-01', 600),
(4, 1, 1, '2019-05-01', 700),
(5, 2, 5, '2019-05-01', 1000),
(6, 3, 3, '2018-05-02', 300),
(7, 3, 2, '2018-05-03', 400),
(8, 1, 3, '2018-05-06', 800),
(9, 2, 4, '2018-05-22', 1100);
```

What i want to do is list ALL the bids from the Bid table, but i want to display the bidders names instead of their bidderNumber. Basically i just want to select all of the bid table but instead of the bidderNumber it will display the name connected to the bidderNumber in the bidder table.

I'm very rookie at mySQL and i find it extremely hard to find information of this specific issue as i cant really descrive what i want to do in short terms. Or perhaps this issue is so glaringly easy that i should know this. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: You are describing a simple INNER JOIN: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Ah yes, i know about joins! The issue i'm facing is the replacing bidderNumber from the bid table with name from the bidder table.

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment and try something.

Comment: You're right @forpas my bad, i believe i might have screwed something up when attempting this myself in the first place. It seems it was the ON syntax i was using poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As torpase described use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

> ```
> SELECT 
> b.bidNumber, b.itemNumber,bi.name , b.bidDate, b.bid
> FROM Bid b 
> INNER JOIN Bidder bi
> ON b.bidderNumber = bi.bidderNumber
> ```
>
> ```
> bidNumber | itemNumber | name         | bidDate    |  bid
> --------: | ---------: | :----------- | :--------- | ---:
>         0 |          0 | Ada Asson    | 2019-04-20 |   50
>         2 |          1 | Beda Bsson   | 2019-05-01 |  500
>         4 |          1 | Beda Bsson   | 2019-05-01 |  700
>         1 |          0 | Ceasar Csson | 2019-04-25 |   70
>         3 |          1 | Ceasar Csson | 2019-05-01 |  600
>         7 |          3 | Ceasar Csson | 2018-05-03 |  400
>         6 |          3 | Dino Dsson   | 2018-05-02 |  300
>         8 |          1 | Dino Dsson   | 2018-05-06 |  800
>         9 |          2 | Eve Esson    | 2018-05-22 | 1100
>         5 |          2 | Fabian Fsson | 2019-05-01 | 1000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=473f0245b22b37c45992af4bebb79725)*

Comment: Thank you! It seems it was the ON syntax i was misusing. If you don't mind me asking, i tried this with and without the ON statement, using the ON statement clearly just imposed every name on every bid there was. Why is this? What does the ON statement specifically do?

Comment: ON descriebs the connection relation between two tables so that mysql knows where to join both tables. Mysql join tbakes row by row and checks if there is a corresponding number.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense :)